# Safe - refund amount is always less than gas fee

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe

I'm trying to send some ether from a safe account to an EOA. However, the refund amount received back is always less than the gas fee. The following code snippet shows how I'm estimating both the base gas and the safe tx gas:

```
safe_tx_estimate = safe.estimate_tx_gas(
        to=to,
        value=Web3.to_wei(value, 'ether'),
        data=b'',
        operation=0,
    )
base_estimate = safe.estimate_tx_base_gas(
        to=to,
        value=0,
        data=b'',
        operation=0,
        gas_token="0x" + "0" * 40,
        estimated_tx_gas=estimation1
    )

safe_tx = safe.build_multisig_tx(
        to=to,
        value=Web3.to_wei(value, 'ether'),
        data=b'',
        safe_tx_gas=web3.to_wei(safe_tx_estimate, 'wei'),
        base_gas=web3.to_wei(base_estimate, 'wei'),
        gas_price=web3.eth.gas_price,
        refund_receiver=obj.executor.address
    )

    ...
 # Sign the multi sig tx
 # simulate the tx
   ...

safe_tx.execute(
        tx_sender_private_key=obj.executor.key,
        tx_gas=web3.to_wei(safe_tx.recommended_gas() + additional_gas, 'wei'),
        tx_gas_price=web3.eth.gas_price
    )
```

The tx executes ok, but from the receipt logs I can see that the `payment` amount is less than expected. I've tried to tweak with the baseGas but with no luck.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: From the provided snippet it's unclear what `estimate_tx_base_gas` and `estimate_tx_gas` are. Most likely the problem is in these functions. For help with them, please create an issue in the corresponding repo.